# How do you use group by and having clause in EF with parent/child relationship?

Tags: entity-framework, having

How can I write a linq to entities query that includes a group by and a having clause?

For example in SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.tblParent p
INNER JOIN  
(
    SELECT a.ID
    FROM dbo.tblParent a 
    join dbo.tblChild c ON a.ID = c.FkParentID
    WHERE a.ColValue = 167
    GROUP BY A.ID
    HAVING COUNT(c.ID) = 1
) t ON p.ID = t.ID
```

Comment: I'm looking for parent records where there is only one child record.

Answer (score 0):

I found my own answer.

```
    // this is far from pretty but it works as far as I can tell
Apps = (from x in context.tblParents
                join t in (
                    from p in context.tblParents
                    join c in context.tblChilds
                        on p.ID equals c.FkParentID
                    where p.ColValue  == 167
                    group c.ID by p.ID into grouped
                    where grouped.Count() == 1
                    select new { grouped.Key }) on x.ID equals t.Key
                select x);
```